# Gulp copy only to new destination

Tags: javascript, node.js, copy, task, gulp

I have a gulp task which copy sub directories and files recursively from a single parent source to multiple destinations. It's something like below.

```
gulp.task('copy-template', function(){
  var srcPath = 'src/template/**/*',
      destPath = ['project1/dest', 'project2/dest'];

          for (var j = 0; j < destPath .length; j++) {
               gulp.src([srcPath]).pipe(gulp.dest(destPath[i]));
          }
});
```

`destPath` is coming from a configuration file that will have more values over time... e.g. more project `'project3/dest'`, `'project4/dest'` etc

Also the `srcPath` may also have new files under the same parent directory

I want to know how I can copy only brand new file **(NOT newer version of an existing file)** to multiple destinations **WITHOUT deleting the existing files** in the destination.

Comment: Can't you just use [fs.exists](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) on the destination? Something like *if (!fs.existsSync(targetFile) do the copying*. Used sync version for brevity, callback could work fine as well.

Comment: I could if I know the file names... but I don't... I could use `gulp-directory-map` but I have about 20-30 files that would grow so is the number of destinations so it could be very expensive? I am hoping I don't have to go down road of creating my own messy solution using `gulp-directory-map` and check if file exists in each directory at dest... hope there is a simpler existing solution to this :-/